# counting combinations of 3 letters

Tags: combinatorics

I have 3 arrays of letters: A, B, C

A is of length $3$ ($A_0$ to $A_2$)

B can be B$_0$ - B$_7$

C can be C$_0$ - C$_5$

Can I calculate the total number of all unique $3$ letter long combinations, without programatically permuting through them?

```
A0 B0 C0
A0 B0 C1
A0 B0 C2
A0 B0 C3
A0 B0 C4
A0 B0 C5
A0 B1 C0
A0 B1 C1
...
```

Comment: There are $3$ options for your `A`.  There are $8$ options for your `B`.  There are $6$ options for your `C`.  Apply the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: how would the rule of product get rid of duplicates for repeating letter arrays?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "*duplicates for repeating letter arrays.*"  Are you implying that any of the three positions can be any of the available letters from any of the arrays and repeats are allowed?  E.g. $A_0B_2A_0$ is a valid 3-letter string?  In that case each position has $3+8+6=17$ options (assuming no overlap) and again by rule of product we have $17\cdot 17\cdot 17$ total options for a three-letter word.  This interpretation of the question however seems incorrect because it makes absolutely no use of the fact that the arrays are of different names and different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Well like @JMoravitz  said, you have $3$ options for the first blank, $8$ options for the second one and $6$ for your third blank. So you get, $6\times8\times3$ = $144$. $$ $$ Normally for questions about combinations related to letters where the letters are the same you remove some combinations as the order doesn't matter but in this case, you have $A_0$ to $A_2$ so these two letters despite being the same have a small difference being their number. So you just calculate the permutations.

Comment: A, B, C is obviously a trivial exercise as all letters are unique. The problem I have is that the sequence can be A, B, C, A, A, C, B, which essentially means that there will be duplicates. My issue is that I need to be able to calculate the distinct count of all combinations in such case.

Comment: @jjj then you need to be **much** clearer what it is you are wanting to count.  For a smaller example where it is only $A_0, A_1, B_0,B_1, and C_0$ I would have thought there were exactly four possibilities: $A_0B_0C_0, A_0B_1C_0, A_1B_0C_0, A_1B_1C_0$.  What further possibilities are you wanting to count?  You give an example of `ABCAACB` which is not a "three letter long combination" and does not follow the rules that anyone would have expected given your original phrasing of the question.

Comment: I am sorry, this was a very badly described problem. I've explained it in this posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612013/formula-for-counting-distinct-n-letter-long-array-permutations and already got the answer. Thanks for your time.